# Does $\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}$ is uniformly integrable?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My question is does $ \frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} $ is uniformly integrable?

Since $W_t \sim N(0,t) \Rightarrow \frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \sim N(0,1)$, I tried to prove it this way:

$\mathbb{E}(|\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}| 1_{\{|\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}|>K\}}) = 2\int_{K}^{\infty}w\frac{e^{-w^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-K^2/2}$

But this expression $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-K^2/2}$ can be as small as we want.
Indeed for any given $\epsilon>0$ you can choose a $K>\sqrt{2ln(\sqrt{2/\pi})/\epsilon}$ that will verify: $\mathbb{E}(|\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}| 1_{\{|\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}|>K\}})< \epsilon$.
So it seems to me that the expression: $\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}}$ is UI, is it correct?

Thank.

Comment: Yes, it’s uniformly integrable. The random variable you are asking about is standard Gaussian. However, you are looking at a Brownian motion in the second half of your question, which is not UI, that’s true.

Comment: @AndrewZhang thk for your answer but i am a little bit confused. Did you mean "it’s NOT uniformly integrable" because you ve written "it’s uniformly integrable" ?

Comment: You are asking about two different things in your question. Brownian motion is not uniformly integrable. This is clear as Brownian motion does not have a limit, or alternatively, optional stopping evidently does not hold for Brownian motion. Your proof is also OK, just giving some other perspectives. If you normalize Brownian motion, then it IS uniformly integrable.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thank i was asking mainly on the prove about that $W_t/\sqrt{t}$ is not UI. Thk to you.

Comment: Yes, $W_t/\sqrt t$ IS uniformly integrable.

Comment: Looks good to me. Another way, any $L^1$ random variable is uniformly integrable by dominated convergence.

Comment: @AndrewZhang thk a lot for your time(sorry before i ve edited my message, the first time i ve made copy paste of not relevetn latex code). Btw can you copy paste the exact last message you ve written me as an answer like this i ll be able to mark this topic/question as solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Andrew Zhang.
I copy past here his answer to mark this topic as solved.

"Looks good to me. Another way, any L1 random variable is uniformly integrable by dominated convergence."